# current_date()+1 is returning invalid date

Tags: sql, mysql

select CURRENT_DATE()+1 is returning 20101032 on Oct 31 in MySQL. How can I fix this? The expected date is 20101101. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

use `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` instead

Comment: Oops, what I was trying to post was `CURRENT_DATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY`, which is just a slightly different phrasing of your answer, but one which I thought some might find more readable. Copy-paste FAIL on my part.

Comment: Apparently I can't edit my original comment, so I just deleted it.

Comment: @ike - Now *that* I did not know.  Nice tip

Answer (score 1):

This also works.    `date(CURRENT_DATE+1)`

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, code only answers are not high quality. A better answer would explain what the code does, tell where to insert it, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.